# What does super.replace() do?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand document filter in Java. I want to know why we call super.replace method and what it does?
I am studying and applying a code for restricting to number only and limited character in Jtextfield.

```
public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                int currentLength = fb.getDocument().getLength();
                if(isDigit(text)){
                int overLimit = (currentLength + text.length()) - limit - length;
                if (overLimit > 0) {
                    text = text.substring(0, text.length() - overLimit);
                }
                if (text.length() > 0) {
                    super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs); 
                }
            }else{
                        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                   //super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);     
                System.out.println("BEEP");
                }
```

isDigit() has the logic to check of Character.isDigit()

On returning true what does super.replace do ? 
Also I am unable to clear the textfield by setText() where i am using documentfilter.

Comment: It depends what the inherited implementation of `replace` does.

Comment: Could you please show us some context? Which class is replace in?

Comment: It will call the replace method from super class. Rest all is dependent on super class's replace method functionality.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was studying code for allowing only number                                                        if (isDigit( text )){
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attributes);
        }else{
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            System.out.println("BEEP");
        }       {Isdigit contains the Logic to check }

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. Code is unreadable in comments. Comments may not appear in order posted but by votes.

Comment: @nomadmaker I added the code pls suggest what super.replace do after if() gets true according to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default implementation of [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html#replace(javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter.FilterBypass,int,int,java.lang.String,javax.swing.text.AttributeSet)) calls the FilterBypass directly:

```
public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
                    AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
    fb.replace(offset, length, text, attrs);
}
```

This means that the text range replacement operation will go ahead without any further filtering.

Source:
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/6bab0f539fba8fb441697846347597b4a0ade428/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.java#L118

Comment: it means as soon i call super.replace then mutation stops and no filtering happens further . please refer my code and make me understand .I will be thankful to you

Comment: It looks like your filter rejects all "replace" edits where the text is not numerical. What happens if the replacement is an empty string?

Comment: Yes as I don't want alpha and character not more than 15 digit because my text field is account num. I am getting trouble for empty string .eg. after submission i am clearing all text field by setText it is working everywhere except my acc and amt field where I am filtering